# Trying to send mouse cordinates to arduino but freezing in python

Tags: python, arduino

I have the following code:

```
import time
import serial
import pyautogui



serial.Serial()

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbmodem141201", 9600)




while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    position = int(pyautogui.position().x / (1440 / 180))
    value = "X"+str(position)+"Y60"
    print(value)
    print(pyautogui.position().x)
    #print(pyautogui.position().x / (1440 / 180));
    
    ser.write(str(value).encode())
    x = ser.readline()
    print(x)
```

Im trying to capture the x cordinate on my screen and send it through serial to my arduino however its not working. it just prints the cordinate and never gets to ser.readline(). I have tried change the write to taking an input and that works.

if i do

```
value = input("enter: ")
ser.write(value.encode())
```

This will work when i manually input values. But when I try to pass x cordinate automatically its not working.

Comment: Probably, the arduino never puts anything on the serial line, so there is no line for `ser.readline()` to read. Are you sure the arduino is sending something back?

Comment: yea I do have a writeln in there because it does work when I input a number manually, as soon as i take the readline out it works automatically. I was thinking maybe its taking too long to read the line but even then it should still work... I dont know what the issue with the read line is..@L.Grozinger

Comment: can you also attach the arduino read code? I guess that your arduino doesn't write anything back...

Answer (score 0):

`serial.readline()` needs to read up to a "\n", which is added on whenever you send commands manually by pressing enter. Try tagging on that to your `serial.write()` when you pass the coordinate.

Comment: tried this     value = "X"+str(position)+"Y60"+"\n" and still didnt work

Answer (score -1):

looks like issue was with the readline. it was causing it to get stuck... anyone know why? once i removed it , it works